# How do I plot a semilog plot in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

How do I plot a semilog plot in python? with X axis in log and y axis as linear. Currently I m plooting phase vs omega where I need the y axes to be linear while x axes to be in log. Hoow can I do that in python?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `semilogx`, as documented [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/log_demo.html)

A quick example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.semilogx([1, 10, 100], [1, 10, 100])
plt.xlabel("Omega")
plt.ylabel("phase")
plt.show()
```

[image]