# Logarithmic scale in a negative domain in Plots.jl

Tags: plot, julia, plots.jl

Consider this minimal example

```
julia> using Plots
julia> pyplot()
julia> x = -100:0.01:100
julia> y = x
julia> plot(x, y, xscale = :log10)
```

This raises the following error:

`DomainError:
log10 will only return a complex result if called with a complex argument. Try log10(complex(x)).`

Of course, this is because the logarithm of negative numbers is not well defined. However, in python you can overcome this problem using the command `plt.xscale('symlog')`. Is there an equivalent command for Plots.jl?

Comment: I can't test it, but is replacing `plot` by [`semilogx`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43434958/how-do-i-plot-a-semilog-plot-in-python) an option?

Comment: @phg it seems `semilogx` is not a valid command name

Comment: There is some mentions to `symlog` (symmetric log scale), but no implementation has be done yet. You should file an issue. See https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+symlog